Error: Cannot find module '/Users/user/directory/app/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.6.4.cjs'
Trying to upgrade from React Native to 0.73.6 to 0.74.2.
React Native upgrade instructions said to add the following

packageManager": "yarn@3.6.4

to package.json and add the following to a file ".yarnrc.yml" with this content. There is no directory yarn/releases/yarn-3.6.4.cjs

nodeLinker: node-modules yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.6.4.cjs

But I now get the following error

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/user/Dir/Dir2/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.6.4.cjs'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

I have attempted to set yarn to berry and have performed corepack enable
Node.js v20.14.0

Finally figured it out. In your project directory and your home directory run remove all yarn files and folders.
$cd ~ && rm -rf .yarn/ && rm -f yarn.lock
then run
$ yarn set version 3.6.4.
I then had issues with Watchman so I ran
$ brew uninstall watchman && brew update && brew install watchman
followed by
$ watchman watch-del-all
$ watchman shutdown-server
Hope this saves you a few hours

seems like removing ~/.yarn is not necessary
this is what worked for me:

before adding .yarnrc.yml, i tried yarn set version 3.6.4

it downloads .yarn/releases/yarn-3.6.4.cjs and updates the package.json (adds the "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.4" line)


run yarn


This answer should be accepted as right one. You indeed don't need to delete yarn folder
